# Android Bluetooth send Data(Text + Picture) to Multiple Devices at the Same time?

Tags: android, bluetooth, device, send

I research about Bluetooth in Android, but it can send data between two device, so It is possible to send data to Multiple devices in Android? if possible, please some hint, or some source code. Thanks;

Answer (score 0):

No. Bluetooth is a point to point communication protocol: it does not support any "single device to multiple other device using the same connection" semantics.

If you want point to multipoint then use something like broadcast or multicast UDP.

Answer (score 0):

True not exactly broadcast but multi-cast / piconet way

Take a look here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth#Communication_and_connection

and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piconet

Answer (score 0):

Although it is a pretty old question,
These days there is the BLE (Bluetooth low energy) technology, which is included in the Android framework which enables you to broadcast data between multiple devices.

[Documentation](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/ble-overview&ved=2ahUKEwjvp_SggdH1AhWMq6QKHSplBRUQFnoECA0QAQ&usg=AOvVaw1lffIaU1hC8-5xeDHpFeVr)